# Push parts of associative array into another

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am wondering how to push certain parts of an associative array resulting from the foreach loop into another array.

Code:

```
foreach ($result as $product) {
    $liveArray = $product['prodid']['title']['unit'];
    insertData($dbh, $product);
  }
} while (!empty($rule)); //Stops loops if last element on page is found
```

$product array after foreach loop:

```
array(5) {
  ["prodid"]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  ["title"]=>
  string(29) "Test item 1"
  ["unit"]=>
  string(4) "100pk "
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "10.99"
  ["wasprice"]=>
  string(4) "11.99"
}
```

I only want ['prodid'],['title'] and ['unit'] from the array and added to $liveArray. Resulting in something like this:

```
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
  ["prodid"]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  ["title"]=>
  string(29) "Test item 1"
  ["unit"]=>
  string(4) "100pk "
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "10.99"
  ["wasprice"]=>
  string(4) "11.99"
}
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
  ["prodid"]=>
  string(6) "123457"
  ["title"]=>
  string(29) "Test item 2"
  ["unit"]=>
  string(4) "50pk "
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "11.00"
  ["wasprice"]=>
  string(4) "13.00"
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
$liveArray = array();
do {
    foreach ($result as $product) {
        $liveArray[] = array(
            'prodid' => $product['prodid'],
            'title' => $product['title'],
            'unit' => $product['unit'],
        );
        insertData($dbh, $product);
    }
} while (!empty($rule)); //Stops loops if last element on page is found
// print_r( $liveArray );
```

Comment: Exactly like that! Thank you for the quick response, I keep thinking there was some magical way that would have made it work and be pretty haha!

Answer (score 1):

// appended as answer for better formatting.

DrDog, if you want a magical way, here it is:

```
$liveArray = array();
$keepKeys = array('prodid' => true, 'title' => true, 'unit' => true, );
/* or more magic
$keepKeys = array('prodid', 'title', 'unit', );
$keepKeys = array_flip($keepKeys);
*/
do {
    foreach ($result as $product) {
        $liveArray[] = array_intersect_key($product, $keepKeys);
        insertData($dbh, $product);
    }
} while (!empty($rule)); //Stops loops if last element on page is found
// print_r( $liveArray );
```